# Tranformar xml en otro xml usando <xsl:apply-templates>

Tags: xml, xsl

Necesito tranformar este **xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="recupera3_04.xsl"?>
<biblioteca2019>
<row>
    <field name="TITULO">SQL SERVER 2000</field>
    <field name="ISBN">84-415-1136-5</field>
    <field name="PRECIO">32.89</field>
    <field name="FECHA_ALTA">2021-06-04 19:22:15</field>
    <field name="AUTOR">FRANCISCO CHARTE OJEDA</field>
    <field name="EDITORIAL">ANAYA MULTIMEDIA</field>
    <field name="TEMA">INFORMATICA</field>
    <field name="SUBTEMA">SISTEMAS GESTORES DE BASES DE DATOS</field>
</row>

<row>
    <field name="TITULO">PROGRAMACIÓN PHP</field>
    <field name="ISBN">84-415-1418-6</field>
    <field name="PRECIO">30.00</field>
    <field name="FECHA_ALTA">2021-06-04 19:22:15</field>
    <field name="AUTOR">ASHISH WILFRED</field>
    <field name="EDITORIAL">ANAYA MULTIMEDIA</field>
    <field name="TEMA">INFORMATICA</field>
    <field name="SUBTEMA">PROGRAMACIÓN PHP</field>
</row>

<row>
    <field name="TITULO">PROGRAMACIÓN PHP</field>
    <field name="ISBN">84-415-1418-6</field>
    <field name="PRECIO">30.00</field>
    <field name="FECHA_ALTA">2021-06-04 19:22:15</field>
    <field name="AUTOR">MEETA GUPTA</field>
    <field name="EDITORIAL">ANAYA MULTIMEDIA</field>
    <field name="TEMA">INFORMATICA</field>
    <field name="SUBTEMA">PROGRAMACIÓN PHP</field>
</row>
</biblioteca2019>
```

Este es el **xsl** que he creado pero me da error de compilación y no estoy seguro de por qué.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
        <biblio2019>
            <xsl:applytemplates/>
        </biblio2019>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="biblioteca2019/row">
    <libro>
        <xsl:attribute name="isbn">
            <xsl:value-of select="row/field[2]/text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <obra>
            <titulo>
                <xsl:value-of select="row/field[1]/text()"/>
            </titulo>
            <autor>
                <xsl:value-of select="row/field[5]/text()"/>
            </autor>
            <categoria>
                <xsl:attribute name="tema" select="row/field[7]/text()"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="subtema" select="row/field[8]/text()"/>
            </categoria>
        </obra>
        <editorial>
            <xsl:value-of select="row/field[3]/text()"/>
        </editorial>
        <precio>
            <xsl:value-of select="row/field[6]/text()"/>
        </precio>
    </libro>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tengo que conseguir otro **xml** con esta estructura:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<biblio2019>
  <libro isbn="ISBN_84-415-1136-5" alta="2019-05-29">
    <obra>
      <titulo>SQL SERVER 2000</titulo>
      <autor>FRANCISCO CHARTE OJEDA</autor>
      <categoria tema="INFORMATICA" subtema="SISTEMAS GESTORES DE BASES DE DATOS"/>
    </obra>
    <editorial>ANAYA MULTIMEDIA</editorial>
    <precio>32.89</precio>
  </libro>
```

Puede que no tenga claro como usar la etiqueta apply-templates. ¿Tengo que crear un template por cada nodo que se vea afectado? Entonces no entiendo como sacaría los atributos en "categoria" y "libro" por ejemplo. Realmente necesito ayuda porque he estado buscando por varias websites y no doy con la solución.

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, añade a tu pregunta el error completo que sale al hacer la transformación

Answer (score 0):

Hay rutas absolutas y relativas.
En la aplicación de la plantilla te conviene usar la ruta relativa, tanto en el `select` como en el `match`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/biblioteca2019">
    <biblio2019>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
    </biblio2019>
</xsl:template>
        
<xsl:template match="row">
    <libro>
        <xsl:attribute name="isbn">
            <xsl:value-of select="field[2]/text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <obra>
            <titulo>
                <xsl:value-of select="field[1]/text()"/>
            </titulo>
            <autor>
                <xsl:value-of select="field[5]/text()"/>
            </autor>
            <categoria>
                <xsl:attribute name="tema">
                    <xsl:value-of select="field[7]/text()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="subtema">
                    <xsl:value-of select="field[8]/text()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </categoria>
        </obra>
        <editorial>
            <xsl:value-of select="field[6]/text()"/>
        </editorial>
        <precio>
            <xsl:value-of select="field[3]/text()"/>
        </precio>
    </libro>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```